# Local storage vs AngularJS $cacheFactory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

I have a problem of storing a lot of client-side data, and I can't decide which way is better. Now I'm using AngularJS's cacheFactory, it works fine, but all data reloads with a new session. Is it worth to use local storage instead?

Comment: Hello you can use webstorage then you can fetch data with a factory, http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Yes localstorage lets you store data without caring about the session. I will also recommend looking at https://parse.com/ for saving data in the cloud instead of a server.

Comment: I ended up going with https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage The Angular-way: No Getter 'n' Setter Bullshit!

Comment: Its worth noting that local storage is not secure

Comment: @mb21 ngStorage is dead, with outstanding crucial PR's

Comment: @Blowsie: why do you say ngStorage is dead?

Comment: @Rodney it has no activity and critical issues.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

If your goal is to store client-side and persistent data, you can't use the [$cacheFactory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory), which just caches the data for the current session.

One solution is to use the new local storage API. [This awesome Angular module](http://gregpike.net/demos/angular-local-storage/demo.html) makes all the dirty job for you, and even falls back to cookies for old browsers!

Comment: No, you should serialize your objects before to store them (and unserialize to read them), typically in JSON. But to store objects directly doesn't make a lot of sens, since all persistent storage is mandatory using files, and so linearized data.

Comment: Vote up for the local storage module mention. Saved me a lot of coding!

Comment: @Rasalom I'm late to the party, but I looked at the source of the localstorage module and it does store objects without the need for you to json encode/decode them yourself (it does it for you). This feature may have been developed after this post, but I wanted to share for future readers.

Comment: The demo page you linked to actually doesn't work, there's an uncaught syntax error in console.

Comment: @CharlieS You can report the problem to the author of the module [on the bugtracker](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage/issues). It should be repaired quickly!

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I didn't see a link to GitHub from the demo page.

Comment: Please note that $cacheFactory does not cache the data for the current session, it caches the data in memory, so only as long as your angular application is alive. A page refresh, for example, kills it. @Blackhole could you update that please to avoid misleading people?

Answer (score 21):

An alternative solution is http://jmdobry.github.io/angular-cache/ which works well with ngResource and can also easily be configured to sync to localStorage, so requests don't need to be re-done after page refresh.

```
$resource('my/kewl/url/:key', { key: '@key' }, {
  'get': { method: 'GET', 
           cache: $angularCacheFactory('MyKewlResourceCache', { 
                                          storageMode: 'localStorage' })
         }
});
```

Comment: I feel like this one is more powerful than the solution from the accepted answer. Thanks about the $resource don't see it in its official website

Answer (score 1):

$cacheFactory seems to be clearly NOT your solution, because as **Blackhole** said, the cache will be cleared each time session expires. $cacheFactory is just a memcache implementation the Angular way.

angular-cache is just an helper API, basically it adds option to $cacheFactory and one of this option is to store cache into persistent storage (like localStorage).

So if you want to store data in persistent storage you can use use one of the module available like [angular-local-storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) or use [$cookieStore](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore) but it will create cookies...

Comment: Again, $cacheFactory does not cache the data for the current session, it caches the data in memory, so only as long as your angular application is alive. A page refresh, for example, kills it. @user3305685 could you update that please to avoid misleading people?

Answer (score 0):

Another angular module that does the job : https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache