# Angular.js: Factory to store value between page refreshes in the DOM?

Tags: angularjs

```
app.factory('theService', function (){
    var member = {
        myValue: false,
    };
    return myValue;
});
```

I have above code and I want to change it to store and give back from the DOM like this

```
app.factory('theService', function (){
    var member = {
        myValue: $window.sessionStorage["myValue"],
    };
    return myValue;
});
```

Effectively make the storage of the boolean myValue persistent between page refreshes. Any other ideas how to solve this in Angular? I am using this in a auth service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use $window in a service. As this makes it very difficult to test the service. Instead you can retrieve the value in your controller and then store it in the service.

Also you should not that based on this MDN page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

It is recommended to use the `setItem()` and `getItem` functions to access values from the `sessionStorage`:

```
myValue: $window.sessionStorage.getItem("myValue"),
```

Comment: Or better, use [an existing module](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19304435/2057033)!

Comment: Or use [angular-cache](http://angular-data.pseudobry.com/documentation/guide/angular-cache/configure) :>

Comment: How to do it between different controllers? e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26097671/access-angular-module-via-service-in-rootscope