# Angular 2 custom caching/local storage

Tags: angular

Is there any tool for custom cache control in angular 2? Local storage?

Went through docs, didn't find any references.

As a temporary solution may use jQuery, but than what the point to use angular?

Regards

Comment: have you considered browser's `localStorage` ?

Comment: I have, but previously in angular 1, the tooling were provided, however I didn't find anything like that in ver 2

Comment: If you are looking for `$cacheFactory ` in `angular2`. I couldn't find it either . But [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304435/local-storage-vs-angularjs-cachefactory) question might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also take a look into this. This is kinda state management provider for Angular2. I don't know if its suitable for your requirement atm,

https://github.com/ngrx/store

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @micronyks and believe that [@ngrx/store](https://github.com/ngrx/store) is a must-have package while developing an Angular app - for state management.

However, I believe there's a more suitable package for cache management: the [@ngx-cache/core](https://github.com/ngx-cache/core) which contains the `Cached` method decorator and caching methods (`has`, `get`, `set`) using the [caching API](https://github.com/ngx-cache/core#usage).

The following example shows the use of API methods:

**anyclass.ts**

```
...
import { CacheService } from '@ngx-cache/core';

@Injectable()
export class AnyClass {
  constructor(private readonly cache: CacheService) {
    // note that CacheService is injected into a private property of AnyClass
  }

  // will retrieve 'some string value'
  getSomeStringValue(): string {
    if (this.cache.has('some-string'))
      return this.cache.get('some-string');

    this.cache.set('some-string', 'some string value');
    return 'some string value';
  }
}
```

And this example shows the use of `Cached` method decorator, and `CacheKey` params decorator:

**anyclass.ts**

```
...
import { Cached, CacheKey } from '@ngx-cache/core';

export class AnyClass { 
  // will retrieve 'some string value'
  @Cached('some-string')
  getSomeStringValue(): string {
    return 'some string value';
  }

  @Cached('some-string')
  getSomeStringValue2(@CacheKey param1: string): string {
    return 'some string value: ' + param1;
  }
}

...
// these are the first executions
console.log(anyClass.getSomeStringValue2('p1'));
console.log(anyClass.getSomeStringValue2('p2'));
...
// will retrieve 'some string value: p1' from `CACHE`
console.log(anyClass.getSomeStringValue2('p1'));

// will retrieve 'some string value: p1' from `CACHE`
console.log(anyClass.getSomeStringValue2('p2'));
```

Here are the list of packages, both for client-side and server-side caching:

- [@ngx-cache/core](http://github.com/ngx-cache/core): cache utility
- [@ngx-cache/platform-browser](http://github.com/ngx-cache/platform-browser): SPA/Browser platform implementation
- [@ngx-cache/platform-server](http://github.com/ngx-cache/platform-server): server platform implementation
- [@ngx-cache/fs-storage](http://github.com/ngx-cache/fs-storage): storage utility (required for server platform)